# What are these functions given by Intel Advisor?

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, intel, intel-parallel-studio

I'm trying to use Intel Advisor to understand hotspot in my application.

These are the compile and linker flags that I'm using:

```
INTEL_OPT=-O3 -simd -xCORE-AVX2 -parallel -ipo -qopenmp -fargument-noalias -ansi-alias -no-prec-div -fp-model fast=2
INTEL_PROFILE=-g -qopt-report=5 -Bdynamic -shared-intel -debug inline-debug-info -qopenmp-link dynamic -parallel-source-info=2 -ldl
```

This is a sample image taken from [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/684714) tutorial:

[image]

This is a screenshot from my application:

[image]

I don't understand what all these functions before `_clone`, `[stack]`, `_start` and `_libc_start_main` are.

Comment: It's the runtime, the thing that loads your program and calls main()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James is correct: things like _clone, [stack], _start and _libc_start_main correspond to CRT, Cray sys libs (if you use Cray env), OMP runtime internals or general system calls .

Also in your profile you don't seem to have any vectorization info enabled (empty "why no vectorization", no peel-remainder break-down, no SIMD Efficiency metrics and so on). Since your compilation flags seems to be reasonable, my next guess is that you are either stripping debug info into separate file or use pretty old ICL version. Removing ipo may also help to enable missed information.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The `INTEL_PROFILER` contains all the flags suggested by Intel Advisor (both for threading and vectorization analysis) and Intel VTune, like [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/605665). The code is already parallelized using omp (so there are omp runtime internals) and I'm trying to improve it. Myabe is because of `ipo` as you're suggesting. Otherwise I don't really understand why my case is so different from the tutorial one.

Comment: I see. What you are concerned about is that SCREEN-SHOT in THREADING tutorial is different from your GUI. The reason is following:  Threading Advisor tutorial is way older than Vectorization Tutorial, so some screen-shots in it might be obsolete, while in fresh Advisor there is more analysis for system calls than before. In general, even if Vectoization is not your main focus, beware that greatest and latest tool capability are much better described in much more up to date "Vectorizatoin tutorial" at https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-advisor-tutorial-vectorization-linux-cplusplus